# Spring bootstrap not loading

Tags: html, css, spring

I pasted some bootstrap templates into my resources/templates folder, and when i start the server and go to the url i mapped the index.html page to, the page loads but the bootstrap is missing. When i use chrome button that comes up in IntelliJ to view your html, it works normally, the bootstrap loads and its all ok.
EXAMPLE:

in my index.html page:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
```

[image]

Here you can clearly see they are both (index.html and bootstrap.css) in the same folder. So why when i launch the spring app and go to the url i get the html page and this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

The error is happening on line 14, and line 14 is:

```
  <link  rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Static resources should go under static folder

[image]

Kindly copy `bootstrap.css` under static folder.

Comment: @Emperor share your project in github, lets take a look or provide the project structure and  debug logs as part of the question